# Finding distance between two points on a line with Turf.js?

Tags: javascript, distance, turf

How do you find distance between points on a line (that is not straight)

I have 2 points along a line representing a road (LINE) how do you find the distance between point #1 and #2 along the road?
[image: photo explination]

The points are not on the line, just beside. is there away to move the points on to the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Turf `nearestPointOnLine` method (see https://turfjs.org/docs/#nearestPointOnLine) it's quite easy to get line distance between those two points.

For a given line string and point, method returns point feature of the closest point on line for the given point. Amongst the returned point feature properties there is also `location` property that tells distance from start of the line string to the point.

So calculating line distance between points with `turf.js` could look something like this:

```js
var line = turf.lineString([
  [14.099827, 46.268079],
  [14.205296, 46.196781],
  [14.317955, 46.142001],
  [14.478555, 46.135357],
  [14.684699, 46.115421],
  [14.723051, 46.150305],
  [14.739833, 46.229955],
  [14.924401, 46.238245],
  [14.917209, 46.311145],
  [14.965153, 46.35914]      
]);

var point1 = turf.point([14.387569, 46.154888]);
var point2 = turf.point([14.808245, 46.222095]);

var snapped1 = turf.nearestPointOnLine(line, point1, {units: 'kilometers'});      
var snapped2 = turf.nearestPointOnLine(line, point2, {units: 'kilometers'});

var distance = Math.abs(snapped1.properties.location - snapped2.properties.location);
console.log('distance: ', distance);
```